# Error when posting data with cURL

Tags: json, powershell, post, curl

I have written the following curl command.

```
curl -v -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u username:password 
-d 'Id=5&Email=add@ress.com&OptInType=0&EmailType=0&DataFields=null&Status=0}' 
https://api.dotmailer.com/v2/contacts
```

However when I run in Powershell, it returns the following error

> "message":"Could not parse the body of the request based on the
>   content type\"application/json\"
>   ERROR_BODY_DOES_NOT_MATCH_CONTENT_TYPE"}

This is the verbose server response

> - Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
> - Trying 94.143.104.204...
> - Connected to api.dotmailer.com (94.143.104.204) port 443 (#0)
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: C:\Program Files\cURL\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
> - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / AES128-SHA
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: C=GB; ST=England; L=London; OU=DDG; O=dotMailer Ltd; CN=*.dotmailer.com
> - start date: 2012-01-16 15:51:40 GMT
> - expire date: 2015-01-16 15:51:40 GMT
> - subjectAltName: api.dotmailer.com matched
> - issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - G2
> - SSL certificate verify ok.
> - Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
>     *POST /v2/contacts HTTP/1.1
>     *Authorization: Basic XXXpdXNlci0zNGFmNWU0NTdmYTJAYXBpY29ubmVjdG9yLmNvbTpzaW1vbmUxMjM=
> - User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> - Host: api.dotmailer.com
> - Accept: application/json
> - Content-Type: application/json
> - Content-Length: 72
> - upload completely sent off: 72 out of 72 bytes
> - HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
> - Cache-Control: no-cache
> - Pragma: no-cache
> - Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> - Expires: -1
> - Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 08:46:46 GMT
> - Content-Length: 139
>
> {"message":"Could not parse the body of the request based on the
>   content type \"application/json\"
>   ERROR_BODY_DOES_NOT_MATCH_CONTENT_TYPE"}
>
> Connection #0 to host api.dotmailer.com left intact

Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting my command right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your data in -d doesn't seem to be in json format. Try [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate json format. Or if you are trying to post text data, use text/plain as Content-type.

Comment: I know. I have also tried the json format `{"Id":5,"Email":"add@ress.com","DataFields":null,"Status":0}` but I still get the same error message as above.

Comment: Yes I do, as I said in my previous comment.